# Azure B2C user loggerd with facebook can change profie value

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

in my azure B2C I use 3 users attribute. Name, Address and PostalCode. When an user create a account on B2C with Facebook, after autorizing in Facebook, the user is redirected in Azure profile page to fill up these 3 fields. Then the creation is complete.
But when I call the "change profil" that I normally use with BC Azure user (email/password) on Facebook user, the page open with 2 empty field without any description. It look like a username-password field. So not possible to update Address, PostalCode or name for Facebook user.

It is normal?

Comment: Hi @Pierre-D: Have you added the Facebook identity provider to your Profile Editing policy?

Comment: Hooo I forgot. THANKS